# css move image on :hover

Tags: html, css

I want to make this website logo slide sideways to the button the user hovers over. So when i hover Contact the "mask" slides over to that button.

[image]

I have 5 menu buttons with one image over the middle button. I want to move the image so it is positioned over the button the user hovers.

The image has class `.logo` and id `#logoID`
the buttons have IDs `#Btn1`, `#Btn2`, `#Btn3`, `#Btn4`, `#Btn5`.
the buttons have class `.BtnC1`, `.BtnC2`, `.BtnC3`, `.BtnC4`, `.BtnC5`.

i just started CSS and have almost no knowledge about it. This is what i have so far and i really appreciate any help or guidance... Thanks!

```
#Btn1:hover ~ #logoID .logo {
    position: -100px
}


#Btn2:hover ~ #logoID .logo {
    position: -50px;
}


#Btn3:hover ~ #logoID .logo {
    position: 0px;
}

#Btn4:hover ~ #logoID .logo {
    position: 50px;
}


#Btn5:hover ~ #logoID .logo {
    position: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please add your markup also, thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Im afraid i´m not even sure what that means :/

Comment: Please provide your HTML. A short explanation of why you're doing what you're doing would be useful also. We might be able to offer guidance towards a more "normal" solution. Does the image return back to the third button when no buttons are hovered?

Comment: The position property doesn't take a numeric value, it takes `static`, `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: So you want the goggles above the menu item they're hovering?

Comment: updated the description and added a picture to make it clear. Im trying to get that, but unfortunately im working out of wordpress so im not writing it manually.

Here is what i have updated with.
where .image_container is the column and .image is the image
`.image_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 43.5%;
}`

Comment: yes @hungerstar, exactly!

Comment: What about something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hzc8gjt7/)?

Comment: yep, like that! Thank you so much!!
The only two things i cant figure out now is how to hide the center picture when i hover over one of the others, and how to apply this to my id #menu-item-919, #menu-item-918 and #menu-item-456.

Comment: @user2765075 you really need to provide some markup (HTML). Unfortunately we can't fine tune an example or even point you in a specific directions without it. All we can do is create and offer generalized solutions. Do you have a link that points to a development version of the site we could look at? How is the image of the goggles currently inserted into the page?

Comment: i get it.. thanks for giving it a good shot. Here is the link to the website as it is right now, and again, i´m really a beginner at this..

Comment: http://temp.motionair.no/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion using `transform: translateX ();`

```
#Btn1:hover #logoID {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}


#Btn2:hover #logoID {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
}


#Btn3:hover #logoID {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

#Btn4:hover #logoID {
    transform: translateX(50px);
}


#Btn5:hover #logoID {
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

Here's some [documentation](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/functions/translateX()) for `translateX`.

Of course, you'd have to fix the values to whatever suits you. Maybe even using percentage values could suit you better for a responsive layout.

Also remember your `~` selector may not be necessary and you might as well get away with using something like `#Btn1:hover #logoID {}`

**Note:** if your logo is on a different level than that of the buttons, then you might need a different selector:

- Use `#Btn1:hover > #logoID` if the logo is directly inside the container.
- Use `#Btn1:hover + #logoID` if the logo is directly after the container (next to its closing tag).
- Use `#Btn1:hover #logoID` if the logo is anywhere else inside the container.

Good luck, that's all I could help without the markup.

Comment: The OPs original selectors won't work, `#logoID` and `.logo` are on the same element. You are right to be worried about the tilde `~` selector.

Comment: Oh, I'll edit my answer then. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hell, we don't even know if the "buttons" are even siblings of the image. OP stated that they're working with WordPress. If this is a WP Menu then I'm thinking we're stumbling in the dark until we see the actual markup. Even without the `~` and if the the id/class combo is fixed, it might not work, lol.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I edited my answer to include all possible (and solvable) cases.

Comment: The site link i www.temp.motionair.no if it would help to see it. If its too much hassle, do anyone have any idea how to get a HTML markup from wordpress?

Comment: This is what StyleBot tells me about your buttons: `a.x-btn.txt.x-btn-square.x-btn-regular`

Answer (score 1):

If you want smooth animation I'd recommend you don't use top. You'd probably want to do this with css transforms that way it'd be hardware accelerated (very smooth) on both desktop and mobile. especially mobile.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.txt').bind('mousedown touchdown', function()
     {
     $('.txt').css('transform','scale(1)');
     
         goToMenu($(this));
     });
});

function goToMenu(menu)
{
     var menuOffset = menu.offset();
     var x = menuOffset.left;
  
     $(menu).css('transform','scale(1.4)');
     $('.imgContainer').css('transform','translateX(' + x + 'px)');
  
}
```

```css
.txt {
  float:left;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-top:60px;
  margin-left:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
    transition:all 0.5s;
  user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.imgContainer {
  transform: translateX(30px);
  transition:all 0.5s;
  position:absolute;
  background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/car.png'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='imgContainer'>

  </div>

<div class='txt' id='menu1'>
  Menu1
  </div>
<div class='txt' id='menu2'>
  Menu2
  </div>
<div class='txt' id='menu3'>
  Menu3
  </div>
<div class='txt' id='menu4'>
  Menu4
  </div>
<div class='txt' id='menu5'>
  Menu5
  </div>
```